# Facing catalyst is not recognized error even after installing Zoho Catalyst CLI in windows

Tags: catalystbyzoho, catalystserverless, zohocatalyst, catalystcloudscale, catalystserve

I have installed Zoho Catalyst CLI from my windows machine by running the command `npm install -g zcatalyst-cli`. Then, I ran the command `catalyst -v` to check if it has been installed. However, I am facing the below error : catalyst: The term 'catalyst' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1 + catalyst --version

- CategoryInfo
  : ObjectNotFound: (catalyst :String) [], CommandNot FoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundexception

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEZi.png)

Even re-installing the CLI has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you installed the Catalyst CLI by using the command `npm install -g zcatalyst-cli` from the Windows Command prompt **Administrator** mode and then try to find the installed version by running the command `catalyst -v`.

If this does not solve your problem, then there might be a problem with your npm finding the globally installed packages. To solve this, run the command `echo %PATH%` if you are using a windows terminal or run `echo $env:PATH` if you are using PowerShell. This will display all your 'Path' system environment variables. If you did not find the npm path in the list, then you have to first add your npm installed path to your system Path variable.

To do this, run the command `npm config list`. This will display your npm installed path. It should be something like "C: \Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm". You need to add this location to your 'Path' environment variable. You can refer to [this](https://www.alphr.com/environment-variables-windows-10/) resource to add a new Path environment variable in Windows.

Once done, Open the Administrator mode of your command prompt and then install the Catalyst CLI and check the version. This solved my problem.